# Ruby on Rails get body object from fcm response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented fcm for push notification in windows ruby on rails. but I'm getting response of send() that is in following format. I need only body attribute's value.I'm pretty new to ruby on rails. please guide how can i achieve it.

```
fcm = FCM.new(server_key)   
options = {
        priority: "high",
        # collapse_key: "updated_score",
        notification: {
            title: "Hi Android",
            body: "Hi, Worked perfectly"
        }
    }
response = fcm.send([device_token], options)
```

This is my response

```
{
  "success": true,
  "data": {
    "body": "{\"multicast_id\":8218758506962978728,\"success\":1,\"failure\":0,\"canonical_ids\":0,\"results\":[{\"message_id\":\"0:1514875371230492%ebb60861ebb60861\"}]}",
    "headers": {
      "content-type": [
        "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
      ],
      "date": [
        "Tue, 02 Jan 2018 06:42:51 GMT"
      ],
      "expires": [
        "Tue, 02 Jan 2018 06:42:51 GMT"
      ],
      "cache-control": [
        "private, max-age=0"
      ],
      "x-content-type-options": [
        "nosniff"
      ],
      "x-frame-options": [
        "SAMEORIGIN"
      ],
      "x-xss-protection": [
        "1; mode=block"
      ],
      "server": [
        "GSE"
      ],
      "alt-svc": [
        "hq=\":443\"; ma=2592000; quic=51303431; quic=51303339; quic=51303338; quic=51303337; quic=51303335,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"41,39,38,37,35\""
      ],
      "accept-ranges": [
        "none"
      ],
      "vary": [
        "Accept-Encoding"
      ],
      "connection": [
        "close"
      ]
    },
    "status_code": 200,
    "response": "success",
    "canonical_ids": [],
    "not_registered_ids": []
  }
}
```

Comment: please post more code, including how you got this message. It looks like a JSON representation of an entire HTTP message, which is why the `body` is a string.

Comment: I don't know why body is getting in string. I need to only body's value

Comment: @Pinki suppose your response is `hash` then you can get body value `hash[:data][:body]`

Comment: Thanks  @Gabbar. I got that but It's in escaped format. can i get directy body object without escaped characters ?

Comment: @Pinki i have given your answer, without escaped characters please check it and feel free to accept/upvote answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suppose your response is `hash`

```
body =  hash[:data][:body].gsub(/[\"]/,"")
```

and out put will be like this: -

```
"{multicast_id:8218758506962978728,success:1,failure:0,canonical_ids:0,results:[{message_id:0:1514875371230492%ebb60861ebb60861}]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can follow ruby [OpenStruct](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/index.html) library, it's something like this

```
object = JSON.parse(response, object_class: OpenStruct)
```

Then you can find based on object value and very nicely explain [here](https://coderwall.com/p/74rajw/convert-a-complex-nested-hash-to-an-object)

Hope to help